Replacing NaN values with zero in pandas merge function with outer join
I am trying to aggregate hourly weather data to a daily level by categorizing how many hours it rained heavy, light, medium, and none. First, I have an original dataset that has all the data for all the locations and the hourly weather data. Next, I use filtering in pandas to filter the dataframes into only the ones with specific values for rainfall. Then, I add a column high/medium/low rain which is a 0 or a 1, being 1 because it met the filter criteria. Finally, I joined the data all back together using merge function.
My issue is that when I do a outer join with .merge in pandas, I get NaN values for columns that did not exist before.
threshold_high = 0.3
threshold_low = 0.1
df.head(5)

df_low = df.loc[(df["PRECIPITATION_IN"] <= threshold_low) & (df["PRECIPITATION_IN"] > 0),]
df_low["low_rain"] = 1

df_medium = df.loc[(df["PRECIPITATION_IN"] > threshold_low) & (df["PRECIPITATION_IN"] < threshold_high),]
df_medium["medium_rain"] = 1

df_high = df.loc[(df["PRECIPITATION_IN"] >= threshold_high),]
df_high["high_rain"] = 1

new_df = df_low.merge(df_medium, how="outer").merge(df_high, how="outer")

display(new_df)

new_df.groupby(["WAREHOUSE_NUMBER","MONTH","DAY","YEAR"])["low_rain","medium_rain","high_rain"].sum()

Right now I am getting an error that says: ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead. Additionally can anyone think of a better way to do this in a more elegant way?

Hi and welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Btw, e-motta's solutions solves your problem, but you should switch your preliminary code with mine, it's more efficient. Also, feel free to upvote the answers.


My issue is that when I do a outer join with .merge in pandas, I get NaN values for columns that did not exist before.

That's the expected behavior, not an issue. Besides, when you call groupby with sum in the next step, NaN will be treated as 0.

Right now I am getting an error that says: ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.

You're trying to index with a tuple containing three strings, when you should be using a list:
new_df = new_df.groupby(["WAREHOUSE_NUMBER","MONTH","DAY","YEAR"])[["low_rain","medium_rain","high_rain"]].sum()


you are right I misphrased my question. You are correct that is expected behavior. Thanks for the tip

Try:
threshold_high = 0.3
threshold_low = 0.1

categories = pd.cut(df["PRECIPITATION_IN"], [0, threshold_low, threshold_high, np.inf], labels = ['low', 'medium', 'high'], right=False, include_lowest=False)

df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(categories, dtype='int', prefix='', prefix_sep='')], axis=1)

print(df)

Use pd.cut to get the categories based on conditions and the thresholds. Then, use pd.get_dummies to get the 0 and 1 values. Finally, use pd.concat with axis=1 to concatenate the data.

You need right=False, include_lowest=False otherwise 0.3 will be mislabeled as 'medium'.

@e-motta Thanks! Would've been nicer if op gave input for us to test
